# How can I set a click listener for a TouchListView?

Tags: android

I downloaded the demo of the [CWAC: TouchListView](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist).

How do I listen for the click event on a `TouchListView`?

Basically I want to set an `OnClickListener` for the `TouchListView`.

Comment: What did you try till now? What are the issues you are having?

Answer (score 2):

You can add it the same way you would add an OnClickListener to a ListView. Read the documentation and examples here: [on the main android documentation page.](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

The call is basically
`listViewInstance.setOnClickListener(listenerInstance)`